# Why do we need biasing components for an RF switch if it is based on active components?

Tags: switches, rf

I would like to know why an RF switch need biasing components if it is based on active components.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Simple answer is that active components used at any frequency need biasing and usually some form of power supply.

If you look at pin diode rf switches they need to be biased correctly to adequately perform the switch function. This means having "biasing components".

Comment: In addition to the previous question, What makes a biasing network and how it affects the switch loss?

Comment: You'll have to be specific about a circuit now but generally resistors make a biasing network.